# Error when running my Asp.net 4 application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am getting this error, and cant figure out what the issue is.

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: 'JobManager.Contact' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="Contact" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
Line 2:      CodeBehind="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="JobManager.Contact" %>
Line 3:  


Source File: /Contact.aspx    Line: 1 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

The code behind syntax is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace JobManager
{
    public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the declaration of the class JobSearchManager.Contact from the codebehind file?

Comment: That is not your code behind.  That's a content page.  Show us your code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you delete and add your form again, if you didn't made modifications too much.

I think this problem is caused by partial class. Let me explain. You can see your class is defined as partial class.

```
public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
```

So there can be another part of Contract class and that part can be corrupted or derived from another class. You can check this.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error seems to tell you, that your class `JobManager.Contact` is not inherited from `System.Web.UI.Page` class or one of its descendants.

So **does it**?

If it does, then you're going to have to provide some of your code as well, namely your page class definition for instance. We'll start from there.

Answer (score 0):

- Check if you have a namespace conflict with another assembly.
- Also delete your bin directory and rebuild your project.